# Spring RequestMethod "POST" not supported while File Upload

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am including File Upload feature in my Spring Security, Spring MVC application.

Here is my JSP page:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload File Request Page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="POST" action="uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" /> 
        File to upload: <input type="file" name="file"><br /> 
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br /> <br /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Upload"> Press here to upload the file!
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Controller Method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    String uploadFileHandler(@RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

                // Creating the directory to store file
                String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
                File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "tmpFiles");
                if (!dir.exists())
                    dir.mkdirs();

                // Create the file on server
                File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()
                        + File.separator + name);
                BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();

                System.out.println("Server File Location="
                        + serverFile.getAbsolutePath());

                return "You successfully uploaded file=" + name;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            return "You failed to upload " + name
                    + " because the file was empty.";
        }
    }
```

MultipartResolver Bean has been declared as shown below:

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver createMultipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    //resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    resolver.setMaxUploadSize(1000000);
    resolver.setMaxInMemorySize(1000000);
    return resolver;
}
```

And my Spring Security HttpSecurity Configuration is:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/testDecorator").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/uploadFile").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/home")
            .authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .successHandler(customSuccessHandler)
            .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").and().csrf()
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");


}
```

When I chose file and submit the form. It is throwing below error:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported
WARNING: Request method 'POST' not supported
```

When I use the same code in another project. It is working fine. I am not getting to know where I went wrong. 
Can someone please guide me where can be the problem?

Regards,
Manju Raghavendra.

Comment: I guess you have a problem with describing URL in your jsp page, try to use action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/uploadFile"

Comment: @Raghavendra You should check  the URL at which this form is getting posted. Request method not supported is a warning only.

Comment: No. It is redirecting to correct url "http://localhost:8080/spring-security/uploadFile" when i submit the form @levgen Pianov

Comment: @PallavJha I am getting HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported error when I submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured a multipartResolver in your config files? It might look something like this:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="78643200"/>
    <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="78643200"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Yes. I did configure that.